# Can't send file from server to client over LAN

Tags: java, sockets, lan

Here is a code snippet of both server side and client side through which a user can request a file from server. The server will send the file.

There's two problems:

- Server side sends empty file.
- When trying to run the code in Local area network it is giving ioexception

I don't understand why sever is sending empty file, please help.

**SERVER SIDE CODE :**

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
 package ftpserverclient.FileClientServer;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 *
 * @author Arnab
 */
public class FileServer {

public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
         { 
             ServerSocket ss=null;
             try
             {  
                 ss=new ServerSocket(8085);
             }
             catch(IOException e)
             { 
                 System.out.println("couldn't listen");
                 System.exit(0);
             }
             Socket cs=null;
             try
             { 
                 cs=ss.accept();
                 System.out.println("Connection established"+cs);
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             { 
                 System.out.println("Accept failed");
                 System.exit(1);
             } 
             PrintWriter put=new PrintWriter(cs.getOutputStream(),true);
             BufferedReader st=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cs.getInputStream()));
             String s=st.readLine();


             String path = s ; 
             System.out.println("The requested file is path: "+path);
             System.out.println("The requested file is : "+s);
             File f=new File(path);
             if(f.isFile())
             { 
                 BufferedReader d=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                 String line;
                 while((line=d.readLine())!=null)
                 {
                     put.write(line);
                     put.flush();
                 }
                 d.close();
                 System.out.println("File transfered");
                 cs.close();
                 ss.close();
             } 
         }

}
```

**CLIENT SIDE CODE :**

```
package ftpserverclient.FileClientServer;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 *
 * @author Arnab
 */
public class FileClient {

public static void main(String srgs[])throws IOException
{
    Socket s=null;
    BufferedReader get=null;
    PrintWriter put=null;
    try
    { 
        s=new Socket("127.0.0.1",8085);
        get=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        put=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);

        String u,f;
        System.out.println("Enter the file name to transfer from server:");
        DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(System.in);
        f=dis.readLine();
        put.println(f);

        File f1=new File(f);



        FileOutputStream  fs=new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\PictureDestination\\a.jpg"));


        while((u=get.readLine())!=null)
        { 
            System.out.println(u);
            byte jj[]=u.getBytes();
            fs.write(jj);
        } 
        fs.close();
        System.out.println("File received");
        s.close();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

At client side , you forgot to write `put.fflush();` after `put.println(f);` while sending file name to server.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found this this thing working .

here are the changes.

changing `String u,f;` to `String f; int u;` and `while((u=get.readLine())!=null)
        { 
            System.out.println(u);
            byte jj[]=u.getBytes();
            fs.write(jj);
        }`
into 
    `while((u=get.read(jj,0,1024))!=-1)
            { 
                fs.write(jj,0,u);
            } 
            fs.close();`

but 1 problem still exists. It is not working ON LAN.

Comment: How did you lookup the server IP address?

Comment: i ran `ipconfig` command in cmd in the server machine and it showed the IP address of the machine

Comment: actually IP address of the server is `192.168.0.2` and i ran client side program from a machine with IP `192.168.0.3` (changing client side code from `s=new Socket("127.0.0.1",8085);` to `s=new Socket("192.168.0.2",8085);` ) then the error occurred .. i e the server side code throwing ioexception i.e. printing `couldn't listen`.