# JAVA file sending system

Tags: java, lan

I am trying to create a program which could send files to another computer on LAN, there are 10 computers in this LAN so I want to send files to the specific one. how can I do that?

Comment: Read about sockets: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349796/cant-send-file-from-server-to-client-over-lan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct way would be this. There are more efficient ways for sure though.

The Sending Machine would have to have this.

```
Socket socket = new Socket("ipaddress_of_machine", SHARED_PORT);
OutputStream oStream = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
File file = new File("Path_to_File");
InputStream iStream = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
for(int readCount = iStream.read(buffer); readCount != -1; readCount = iStream.read(buffer)) {
   oStream.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
}
oStream.flush();
oStream.close();
iStream.close();
```

The Receiving machine would have to have something like this.

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SHARED_PORT);
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
InputStream iStream = socket.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream oStream = new SocketOutputStream("filename");
byte[] buffer = new byte[8921];
for(int readCount = iStream.read(buffer); readCount != -1; readCount = iStream.read(buffer)) {
       oStream.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
    }
    oStream.flush();
    oStream.getFD().sync();
    oStream.close();
    iStream.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

That can be done in a multitude of ways, lets give you a couple of examples:

- By FTP
- By SFTP
- By a network mount
- By SCP over SSH
- Via a message bus system (probably the most complicated for your needs.

For all of these examples, there's a lot of good examples and documentation which you will find when Googling for it.

You need to define a more clear problem statement why this needs to be done programatically (if that is what you are asking for) and with which language/which techniques.